# How do I emulate changing the orientation of my android device?

Tags: eclipse, android-emulator

I'm working in Eclipse using the Android SDK and Android ADT plugin, and I have some functionality based on phone orientation that I want to test in the emulator (more specifially, I want to verify my solution to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774645/android-app-resets-on-orientation-change-best-way-to-handle)).

How do I emulate the orientation change?

Comment: Did you even try searching for your problem: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991318/how-to-change-emulator-screen-orientation :)

Comment: Yes, but apparently I was lousy at choosing my search terms. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean,switching during runtime,than:

.Switch to previous layout orientation (for example, portrait, landscape): KEYPAD_7, Ctrl-F11
.Switch to next layout orientation (for example, portrait, landscape): KEYPAD_9, Ctrl-F12

Is that what you need?