# Why does my ListView become null after an orientation change in my Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In one of my `Fragments` I have a method I call from the parent `Activity`. The method is nothing special, it simply scrolls my `ListView` to a position.

```
public void scrollToSomething() {
    mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(The position I supply);
}
```

When I call this method initially, it works just like I expect, but when I rotate my device and call it again, I throw a `NullPointerException` from my `ListView`. I'm very much lost as to why this is happening. I've tried calling `setRetainInstance(true)`. I've tried checking to see if my `ListView` is null before I call the method and if it is, then I initialize it again, but this does not work either. I've tried changing my `onCreateView` in a few different ways, thinking maybe something is going wrong there.

**onCreateView**

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /* The View for the fragment's UI */
    final ViewGroup mRootView = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_base,
            container, false);
    /* Initialize our ListView */
    mListView = (ListView)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_list_base);
    return mRootView;
}
```

The `Fragment` is attached to a `ViewPager` using a simple `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. I've tried carefully looking through the `onDestroy` methods of my `Fragment` and the parent `Activity` to see if I'm calling something that may cause the error, but nothing stands out. I'm not sure if what I'm experiencing is some sort of bug, or if I'm just overlooking something. Any help or advice would be huge. I'm not entirely sure what else to add because I'm just pretty lost as why this is happening, but if anyone has a question, I'll post any code you may see fit.

Comment: Based on your title, perhaps the problem is simply that Activities "reset" when you change orientation": [Android app resets on orientation change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774645/android-app-resets-on-orientation-change-best-way-to-handle), and [Android: handling runtime changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Comment: Sounds like scrollToSomething() is getting called before your fragment  has had a chance to call onCreateView(). It could also be that your activity is holding a reference to an old fragment. When exactly in the lifecycle is the scrollToSomething() method being called, btw?

Comment: @paulsm4 Tried it, doesn't work. It was a good idea though. I thought it might work.

Comment: @Krylez `scrollToSomething` is only called when I touch a particular `LinearLayout` with on `onClickListener`. The data in my `ListView` shows up no matter the orientation, it only seems to be that particular method that's giving me problems.

Comment: If the LinearLayout and ListView are both in the Fragment, try adding the listener in the Fragment creation. That way your reference shouldn't ever be null (famous last words).

Answer (score 5):

This may help you

If your `android:targetSdkVersion="12"` or less:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
```

If your `android:targetSdkVersion="13"` or more:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screensize">
```

Comment: Actually, this did the trick. Would you mind briefly explaining, if you could, why my `ListView` became null otherwise, please?

Comment: This depends upon your code how you used to populate the data in list view. Anyway is it working fine now?

Comment: It seems to only work as long as I add `screenSize` the to `configChanges` and some of the `Views` inside the `Adapter` I attach to my `ListView` become much larger on an orientation change, but as far as that particular method, `scrollToSomething`, it works like it should.

Comment: As your is android:targetSdkVersion="13" or higher . that’s-why you android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screensize" is like this

Comment: Yes, that's why I added `screenSize`.

Comment: So, after a little more testing it's occurred to me that this won't work. Also, as it turns out it's not my `ListView` that's null, but rather my `Fragment`. `getActivity()` is returning null as well as `getView()`. I suppose it has something to do with my `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and my `ViewPager`, but that's a different question now.